# Render table is not fit inside pdf using DOMPDF in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework, dompdf

I have the following piece of code taken from controller,

```
        ...
        $this->view->vCount = count($result);
        $this->view->Reportlist = $result;
          // create view object
        $html = new Zend_View();
        $html->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts/');
        $html->assign('Reportlist', $this->view->Reportlist);
        $html->assign('vCount', $this->view->vCount);

        // render view
        $bodyText = $html->render('getreport.phtml');     
        //echo $bodyText; exit;
        //error_reporting(E_ALL);

        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $dompdf->set_paper("a4","portrait");
        $dompdf->load_html($bodyText);

        $dompdf->set_base_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream($report_date.".pdf");
        .....
```

Above code generates pdf with my html content. But table is not inside pdf. HTML content render only half of the pdf. How can we make fit to PDF using DOMPDF ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "table is not inside pdf." There's nothing in your PHP that looks problematic. Can you post a sample HTML document as well as the resulting PDF?

Comment: @Brian Thanks, Actually my table has 6 column,only 4 column is getting display in pdf , remaining 2 column has gone out of the pdf...how can we make it perfect...

Comment: I see, so the table is rendering too wide to fit on a page? Switch to landscape? There's only so much you can do to correct issues with column width, but if you can post a sample document I'll take a look.

Answer (score 3):

DOMPDF has some issues with css and tables. Best practices are to avoid cell or rowspans and not using external css files. Also only a limited set of css rules are supported. Check out the full compatibility list:
http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility

For fixing you're problem have you tried setting the width of the table:

```
<table width="90%">.. Your data here </table>
```

**Edit: try putting the table in a  `<div></div>`. This solved some generous errors**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately to fit the table inside PDF using DOMPDF is impossible. The DOMPDF team are still working on it and I can say that it is on top list between issues. You can follow this link to learn more about this bug...

[DOMPDF issue](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/98)

I would recommend you to use MPDF to fix your issue. I just now checked MPDF, it worked nice.

Answer (score 0):

All your content inside td elements should be in one line with opening and closing tags of td elements, adding new lines breaks rendering of table.

Change from:

```
<tr>
<td>
    Some of your content<br/>
    some other content
</td>
```

To:

```
<td>Some of your content<br/>some other content</td>
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

It is POSSIBLE to fit a table in a page and you can use CSS for this (either inline or in head tag).

Ensure that you don't have styles table defining parameters like *width="78"* or something like that.